# "esti turnita" vs "turniĝi"

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between saying something like "ĝi estis turnita" vs "ĝi turniĝis"? My guess is that the former means that "it" has been turned *by something*, whereas the latter means that "it" was *rotated* (and not necessarily by something).

**Current understanding**

- "Li turnas la aferon" - transitive action of turning something
- "La afero estas turnita de li" - passive action of being turned by something
- "La afero turniĝas" - reflexive action of turning (not necessarily by something)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Mi turnas la radon* means that "I turn the wheel", in other words I cause the wheel to turn. Thus *turni* means to turn, to rotate someone/-thing, even figurative (see [*turni* in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#turni)).

The suffix *-iĝi* in *turniĝi* points to the subject itself. So *la rado turniĝis* means "The wheel turned". Also this kind of turning can be figurative (see [*turniĝi* in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#turni%C4%9Di)).

There are three verb endings, *-i, -igi* and *-iĝi*. The exact meaning of the two first ones depends on the character of the root, whether it's noun-, adjective- or verb-like (This is one of the hardest parts of Esperanto). However the last ending, *-iĝi*, always means "to become… (by oneself)".

What might confuse many English-speakers, is the fact, that the very strict word order of English creates a need to use the passive voice much more than is needed in Esperanto. So you're almost always better off with simple forms like *turn(iĝ)is* instead of complex forms like *estis turn(iĝ)ita*. And if you need passive voice, favour the *oni* passive.

As a final remark regard those complex forms *esta/i/os …-a/i/onta* more like as descriptions of a state during/after/before the act than the current/past/future act itself, i.e. *La rado estis turnita* : the wheel **was** turned instead of the wheel **had been** turned (or something like that).